# Android Custom Event Listener not triggering

Tags: java, android

Here is my code, I would expect for my log output to go A B C, but it just goes to A and B. I've never had to implement my own event listener, but I don't know what could be wrong. Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
...
OnCompletedEvent listener;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
}

public void ButtonPressed (View view){
    Log.d("LOG","A");
    longRunningTask();
    listener = new OnFinishedValidatingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFinished() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        afterFinished();
    }
    };
}

public void longRunningTask(){
...
Log.d("LOG", "B");
}
public void afterFinished(){
...
Log.d("LOG", "C");
}
public static interface OnCompletedEvent {
    public void onFinished();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont call it anywhere, for example you need to do `listener.onFinished()` somewhere

you should also probably create your listener before your "long running task" in-case your task finishes real quick, otherwise your listener will be null

Comment: Thank you so much. Guess I've been looking at it for too long. Heh. Thanks again.